# Azure Entra ID Groups versus Sync'd AD Groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am integrating a SAML application with Entra ID.  I got everything talking and verified access by assigning some users (AD Sync'd) directly to the Enterprise Application.  Once we were happy with the settings, I added one of the Windows AD Groups (AD Sync'd) up from the custom's AD.  It turns out these groups are not Security Enabled to so can't inherit the Enterprise Application's user role.  If I create a Group in Entra, assign AD Sync'd users and set it to grant membership to the Enterprise App, everything works great.  I read the docs and found out that groups can only be SecurityEnabled at creation.  So I am stumped - why would I not be able to use these groups sync'd over from AD?  It seems like a natural way to reuse systems put in place on-prem to manage these group memberships. I may be coming at this sideways but my Azure-foo is not strong on Identity.  Is there another approach I should be taking?